# How to get data from two tables for one drop-down menu

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 database tables like so:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `banners` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `long_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

And:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `locations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `banner_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `district_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `number` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=511 ;
```

I use the code below to pull a list of locations based on their district_id and create a drop-down menu:

```
$query = 'SELECT id, banner_id, location FROM locations WHERE district_id =' . $district_id;

$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
if (!result) {
die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '"';
if($row['id'] == $location) { echo ' selected';} ;
echo '>' . $row['location'] . '</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
```

But I'd also like to add to the list the `name` from the `banners` table that matches the `banner_id` for each location. So I can echo out `$row['name']` with each `$row['location']`:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '"';
if($row['id'] == $location) { echo ' selected';} ;
echo '>' . $row['name'] . ' ' . $row['location'] . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: do a join on your query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a JOIN query. Try following:

```
$query = 'SELECT l.id, l.banner_id, l.location, b.name
          FROM locations l
          INNER JOIN banners b ON (l.banner_id = b.id)
          WHERE district_id =' . $district_id;
```

Now you have both `name` and `location` in your resultset:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '"';
  if($row['id'] == $location) { echo ' selected';} ;
  echo '>' . $row['name'] . ' ' . $row['location'] . '</option>';
}
```

**Edit**: sidenotes

- [mysql_](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) extension is deprecated, you should use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli_](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php)
- In order to prevent SQL injection, you need to perform input filtering and/or use parameterized queries. Quickest way for your case is to cast `$district_id` to integer. For more information please see [OWASP guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: assuming that both tables can be accessed via one connection

Comment: Do I still need to use parameterized queries even if $district_id is generated by another drop down menu which limits the user to selecting predetermined values?

Comment: Limiting user in html or javascript ( = frontend) does not add any security at all. It is always possible to bypass frontend validations. You should not rely on them. For example by using Chrome's web developer toolbar, attacker can easily modify html/javascript on his browser to send whatever value he wants.

Comment: Thanks, mesutozer! Will do.

Answer (score 0):

Use JOINS  inorder to get the corresponding banner name for two tables
Like
     select banners.*,locations.* where locations.banner_id=banner.id

Answer (score 0):

Here is mysql query which will excute desire results.

```
$query = "select locations.id, 
                 locations.banner_id, 
                 locations.location, 
                 banners.name, 
                 banners.id 
          from locations, banners 
          WHERE banners.id=locations.banner_id 
          and district_id =" . $district_id;
```

Comment: I used this in another scenario. Thank you!